# Marionette 'could not find template' - load external templates

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I'm new with backbone, and also marionette. Idk why I'm get this error. My structure seems correct, but the error persists.

This is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main App -->
    <div id="main-area"></div>

    <!-- Templates -->
    <script id="main-tpl" src="templates/main.tpl" type="text/x-template"></script>

    <!-- 3rd party Dependencies -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/backbone.wreqr/lib/backbone.wreqr.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/backbone.babysitter/lib/backbone.babysitter.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/marionette/lib/backbone.marionette.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // External templates load
    _.each(document.querySelectorAll('[type="text/x-template"]'), function (el) {
        $.get(el.src, function (res) {
            el.innerHTML = res;
        });
    });

    var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
    _.extend(App, {
        Controller: {},
        View: {},
        Model: {},
        Page: {},
        Scrapers: {},
        Providers: {},
        Localization: {}
    });
    App.addRegions({
        Main: '#main-area'
    });
    App.addInitializer(function (options) {
        var mainView = new App.View.Main();
        try {
            App.Main.show(mainView);
        } catch(e) {
            console.error('Error on Show Main: ', e, e.stack);
        }
    });

    App.View.Main = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: '#main-tpl'
    });

    (function(App) {
        'use strict';
        App.start();
    })(window.App);

    </script>
</body>
```

and my `template/main.tpl` is only test html.

```
<div>sounds</div>
```

All 3rd party dependencies paths are correct.

The error that appears is this: 
`Error: Could not find template: '#main-tpl'`

Can someone tell me where am I wrong?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I think the problem is because `$.get` is async and the template load after backbone try to render, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your HTML and replace

```
<script id="main-tpl" src="templates/main.tpl" type="text/x-template"></script>
```

with

```
<script id="main-tpl" type="text/html">
   --- template code ---
</script>
```

Or use [requireJs !text](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text) plugin to load template files into marionette views.

Comment: But this part of code do this

    `_.each(document.querySelectorAll('[type="text/x-template"]'),   function (el) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the template loads after the app initialization.

Instead, try this:

```
$(function () {
  var tplList = document.querySelectorAll('[type="text/x-template"]');
  var tplCounter = 0;
  _.each(tplList, function (el) {
    $.ajax({
      'url': el.src,
      success: function (res) {
        el.innerHTML = res;
        ++tplCounter;
        if(tplCounter == tplList.length){
          App.start();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```